# Unstable wifi/Connection drops with Qualcomm QCA9377 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, acer

So I have dualboot on my Acer Aspire with Linux Lite XFCE(Ubuntu) and Windows 10.

Network Controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac

A while ago I started having issues with Wifi connection regularly dropping when I was on Linux. Pinging my router (192.168.1.1) gave no result, but the Wifi icon identified that I was still connected. This was happening once in every 15 minutes or so and the fix was reconnecting or waiting a couple of minutes. Obviously, this is really annoying as I can't really work on my laptop because of this.

Under Windows Wifi works fine, no issues like that.

I found [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125262/qca9377-unstable-wifi-connection-on-ubuntu-16-04). I don't have access to the router I'm using and I'm sure there's a Linux solution because the issue doesn't exist on Windows.

Here's the wireless-info script result https://pastebin.com/Z4mZjaNd

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525272)'s solution did not work for me (changing router's bandwidth from auto to 20MHz)

Comment: Can you add the output to the question?

Comment: @Freddy so I managed to change the bandwidth and it seems to be working better now. If there will be no issues in the next couple of days, I'll close the question

Comment: So I changed the bandwidth from auto to 20MHz on both the repeater I'm using and the AP, and the connection is still unstable.

Comment: @RalfFriedl what do you mean by "output"?

Answer (score 3):

I'm experiencing a similar issue with the same chipset on my Debian while using 5GHz networks. Everything works as expected using 2.4Ghz ones.

I tested all the ones available at `https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA9377/hw1.0` and the very same problem persisted using all the three API6 files (i.e. firmware-6.bin_*).

The latest (in terms of release date) API5 file firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00023-QCATFSWPZ-1 seemed to work much better but I still experienced the issue after few solid hours.

Eventually, the file firmware-5.bin_CNSS.TF.1.0-00267-QCATFSWPZ-1 seems to be the most stable on my Lenovo Ideapad 320 using:

```
Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

So try renaming the existing firmware-5.bin and firmware-6.bin files under `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/` and use the firmware version I've mentioned. In other words...

```
$ cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/
$ sudo mv firmware-5.bin firmware-5.bin.orig
$ sudo mv firmware-6.bin firmware-6.bin.orig
$ sudo wget "https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA9377/hw1.0/CNSS.TF.1.0/firmware-5.bin_CNSS.TF.1.0-00267-QCATFSWPZ-1?raw=true" -O firmware-5.bin
```

Now load the new firmware and double-check

```
$ sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
$ sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
$ sudo dmesg | grep ath10k

ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 target 0x05020001 chip_id 0x003821ff sub 17aa:0901
ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 0 tracing 0 dfs 0 testmode 0
ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver CNSS.TF.1.0-00267-QCATFSWPZ-1 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 d6b81b3c
ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board-2.bin
ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 8aedfa4a
ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
```

Make sure the version id just next to firmware ver matches.